# Display Array differently

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having a problem with displaying array.

This is how I call it(it's multi_text option from Redux Framework):

```
$my_theme['custom_sidebar_name'];
```

And this is the output:

```
array(12) {
    [0]=> string(10) "Test 1"
    [1]=> string(4) "Test 2"
}
```

But I would like to display it like this:

```
string(12) "Test 1|*|Test 2|*|"
```

I have tried with implode option:

```
$sides=implode('|*|', $my_theme['custom_sidebar_name']);
```

But all I got was:

```
string(12) "Test 1|*|Test 2"
```

So, how I can do it properly and how I can get those "|*|" on the last place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either do

```
$sides = implode('|*|', $my_theme['custom_sidebar_name']) . "|*|";
```

or

```
$array = $my_theme['custom_sidebar_name'];
$string = "";
foreach ($array as $value) {
  $string .= $value . "|*|";
};
```